# Как на java преобразовать строку в число с обрезанием лишних симовлов

Tags: java, строки, преобразование

Имеется строка, содержащая число с несколькими знаками после запятой. Как при преобразовании в число обрезать лишние знаки? Скажем допускается только один знак после запятой, а в строке имеется 2 или 3. Надо получить число без этих лишних знаков. Как это сделать попроще?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new BigDecimal("35.3456").setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
// result = 35.3456
```

`setScale(4` - вот тут 4 означает количество знаков после запятой
`RoundingMode.HALF_UP` - округление вверх

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант округления с N точностью: `Math.round(y * 100.0) / 100.0;`